# How to make a grid of Plotly Indicator gauges?

Tags: python, plotly, gauge, streamlit

I'm trying to use plotly to arrange [gauges](https://plotly.com/python/gauge-charts/) in a grid layout (to give us a Streamlit dashboard showing SLO gauges for a group of teams).

I can't use subplots because they're not compatible with Indicators:

```
ValueError: Trace type 'indicator' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy' at grid position (1, 1)
See the docstring for the specs argument to plotly.subplots.make_subplots for more information on subplot types
```

What's the most elegant (least code) way to arrange gauge Indicators in a grid?

Comment: you can use subplots for none xy grids,  need to provide appropriate params.  edit you question to include a reproducible example.  I can't start to answer without more context

Comment: @quantoid How did the provided suggestions work out for you?

Answer (score 3):

- have synthesized data to match what you have described
- `subplots()` can be used, [subplot types](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-types) Have used a **list comprehension** to build this requirement
- clearly more beautification is required for this example, titles are overlapping gauges

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

# a bit of data to generate guages from...
df = pd.DataFrame({"team":["sprint 1", "sprint 2", "qa"],"backlog":[45,55,22],"defects":[23,44,33]}).set_index("team")

# need to define types of subplots...
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=len(df),
    cols=len(df.columns),
    specs=[[{"type": "indicator"} for c in df.columns] for t in df.index],
)

for r, team in enumerate(df.index):
    for c, measure in enumerate(df.columns):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number", value=df.loc[team, measure], title={"text":f"{team} - {measure}"}),
            row=r + 1,
            col=c + 1,
        )

fig.update_layout(margin={"l": 0, "r": 20, "t": 50, "b": 0})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`go.Indicator` is a [gauge chart](https://plotly.com/python/gauge-charts/) and has a special attribute `domain` that will let you place your indicators within a figure object by specifying `x and y` between `[0, 1]`. Take a look at [Indicators in Python](https://plotly.com/python/indicator/) for this example:

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    value = 200,
    delta = {'reference': 160},
    gauge = {
        'axis': {'visible': False}},
    domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 0}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    value = 120,
    gauge = {
        'shape': "bullet",
        'axis' : {'visible': False}},
    domain = {'x': [0.05, 0.5], 'y': [0.15, 0.35]}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 300,
    domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 1}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "delta",
    value = 40,
    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 1}))

fig.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 2, 'columns': 2, 'pattern': "independent"},
    template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
        'title': {'text': "Speed"},
        'mode' : "number+delta+gauge",
        'delta' : {'reference': 90}}]
                         }})
```

And for those who like to study these things in detail:

> |      The 'domain' property is an instance of Domain  |      that
> may be specified as:  |        - An instance of
> :class:`plotly.graph_objs.indicator.Domain`  |        - A dict of
> string/value properties that will be passed  |          to the Domain
> constructor  |        |          Supported dict properties:  |
> |              column  |                  If there is a layout grid,
> use the domain for  |                  this column in the grid for
> this indicator  |                  trace .  |              row  |
> If there is a layout grid, use the domain for  |                  this
> row in the grid for this indicator trace .  |              x  |
> Sets the horizontal domain of this indicator  |                  trace
> (in plot fraction).  |              y  |                  Sets the
> vertical domain of this indicator  |                  trace (in plot
> fraction).